# Query Maximum VARRAY value

Tags: sql, oracle, varray

How can I query for the maximum value inside a `varray`?

```
create type myWave as varray(10) of int;
create table foo (id number, yVals myWave);

insert into foo values (1, myWave(1, 8, 5));
insert into foo values (2, myWave(1, 3, 4));
insert into foo values (3, myWave(9, 5, 9));
insert into foo values (4, myWave(8, 2));
```

Incorrect SQL: `SELECT id, MAX(yVals) maxY FROM foo`

Desired output:

```
| id | maxY |
|----|------|
|  1 |    8 |
|  2 |    4 |
|  3 |    9 |
|  4 |    8 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.ID, MAX(t2.column_value)  FROM foo t1, TABLE(t1.yVals) t2 group by t1.ID
```